# Why does the R Type Provider crash with these string arguments and not with others?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I noticed something strange with the `R Type Provider`.

In the code below `mat` is of type `list<list<float>>` and all lists of floats have the same length.

The following code generates an exception:

```
let tmp : list<string*list<float>> =
        [0..(mat.Length - 1)]
        |> List.map (fun i -> string i, mat.[i])

    let tmp' = tmp |> List.map (fun (str, x) -> "A" + str, x)

    let tmp' =
        tmp'
        |> namedParams
        |> R.cbind

    let tmp =
        tmp
        |> namedParams
        |> R.cbind
    tmp

Exception thrown: 'RDotNet.ParseException' in RDotNet.dll
Status Error for base::`cbind`(0=fsr_7784_27, 1=fsr_7784_28, 2=fsr_7784_29, 3=fsr_7784_30, 4=fsr_7784_31, 5=fsr_7784_32, 6=fsr_7784_33, 7=fsr_7784_34, 8=fsr_7784_35, 9=fsr_7784_36, 10=fsr_7784_37, 11=fsr_7784_38, 12=fsr_7784_39, 13=fsr_7784_40, 14=fsr_7784_41, 15=fsr_7784_42, 16=fsr_7784_43, 17=fsr_7784_44, 18=fsr_7784_45, 19=fsr_7784_46, 20=fsr_7784_47, 21=fsr_7784_48, 22=fsr_7784_49, 23=fsr_7784_50, 24=fsr_7784_51, 25=fsr_7784_52)
 : unexpected '='
```

However, if the last definition of `tmp` is removed the code runs with no problems. It looks like having strings like `"0"` and `"1"` instead of `"A0"` and `"A1"` is the reason for the exception.

```
let tmp : list<string*list<float>> =
        [0..(mat.Length - 1)]
        |> List.map (fun i -> string i, mat.[i])

    let tmp' = tmp |> List.map (fun (str, x) -> "A" + str, x)

    let tmp' =
        tmp'
        |> namedParams
        |> R.cbind

    //let tmp =
    //    tmp
    //    |> namedParams
    //    |> R.cbind
    tmp

// No exceptions
```

Any explanations for this behavior?

Comment: Not familiar with R so I'm just guessing, but maybe the `cbind` function is expecting variable names before the `=`, and a number like 0 isn't a valid variable name, but `A0` is a valid variable name?

Comment: Maybe, I used to program in R, then I moved to Python then to F#, so I forgot most of what I knew about R. In any case what was passed was a string in both cases.